# Liferay: How do I add an organization page?

Tags: liferay

I want to add an organization page. There is a menu "pages" in the organization configuration, but there isn't a link or something to add a page. How do I add an organization page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose the organization in the second controlpanel section, the Pages link there does work (which version are you on?)

You can also start through ControlPanel/Portal/Organization and choose "Manage Pages" from the organization in question.

On both forms, there's by default a "New Page" form that you can use to add a new page